# php replaces on every line even though multiline not specified

Tags: php, regex

I extract the first line of a tab delineated text string using this:

```
$column_pattern = "/(.*?)\r\n/";
preg_match($pattern, $tsv, $columns);
print_r($columns[0]);
```

This successfully prints the first line of the text string. However, I would like to remove it so I have every line after this. However this

```
$rows = preg_replace($column_pattern, "", $tsv);
echo $rows;
```

replaces every row in the string. But I haven't used the multi line flag in the regex. Why would this behave like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MULTiLINE` doesn't mean what you think it does. `MULTiLINE` just means that line start/end anchors `^` and `$` are matched for every line separated by newline characters.

`preg_replace` will apply the replacement string as many times as possible (match is found).

Answer (score 1):

multiline means a match can span multiple lines, not that it will only look at the *first* line.